# Network Support Explained

Tags: mobile-network

Is a phone that supports the most network bands ideal if you are trying to get the best cellphone service?

I have noticed that for example the iPhone supports dozens of bands https://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/ while many Android phones may only support a couple bands in 2G/3G/4G etc...  http://www.china-prices.com/phone/bands/10024/doogee-bl12000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is a phone that supports the most network bands ideal if you are trying to get the best cellphone service?

It simply depends on the match between your phone modem (radio) capabilities and the band used by Telco(s) where you plan to use them. Other than this having capability to function in bands *other* than those your Telco(s) or carriers use neither adds nor detracts performance

It is a marketing decision to cater to a few bands which are reagion specific or broader (*International* models). Apple is more consolidated than splintered Android and that could be a reason for support to bigger range of bands

**No**

If you have a set of bands that your phone can support but are not supported by your carriers. Capability has no use

**Yes**

If your carrier(s) (as in roaming) support different bands and your phone supports them, it is good because your phone will work on all of them

Aside,  you can see performance in the same mode [widely varies within networks](https://www.androidauthority.com/state-of-mobile-networks-usa-2017-747586/)

Comment: Hmm if you area has 4G support will all bands be broadcasted and work successfully?  Also I'm assuming some bands have longer ranges then others or something but not sure.

Comment: Bands supporting 4G will work.  Some network operators in US *customise* their networks for higher speeds (when it is a carrier  locked device) so their takes and speeds will be better but other 4G bands will work but with lesser performance